# How to update record into two tables at the same time?

Tags: php, pdo

I have here the code for updating but I want to update two tables at the same time. How can I do that?

**Here is the code I'm trying**

```
public function update($user_id,$username,$password,$province)
{
  try
  {
    $stmt=$this->db->prepare("UPDATE login, sample SET login.username=:username,login.password=:password,login.province=:province sample.username=:username,sample.password=:password WHERE login.user_id=:user_id and sample.id=:id");
    $stmt->bindparam(":username",$username);
    $stmt->bindparam(":password",$password);
    $stmt->bindparam(":province",$province);
    $stmt->bindparam(":user_id",$user_id);
    $stmt->bindparam(":id",$id);
    $stmt->execute();
    return true;
  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Update first one, Then update next

Comment: i already tried to update from a single table and it's working fine but when i try the code above its not updating the 2 two tables..

Comment: Use transactions: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php

Comment: create a stored procedure and call that from your php code - let the db do the heavy lifting

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
update db1 inner join db2 on db1.username = db2.username 
   set db1.user_level = 1,
       db2.user_level = 1
  where db1.username = 'a';
```

Comment: can i do that even there's no relationship between the tables?

Comment: i already tried your code but it;s not working..here's what i do $stmt=$this->db->prepare("UPDATE login inner join sample on login.username = sample.username SET login.user_level = 1, sample.user_level=1 WHERE login.username='a');

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your two queries inside a transaction. Read more: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php